# Load popup only based on session timeout

Tags: magento2, session, popup

I have initialized a popup

```
var popup = modal(options, $('#notification-modal'));
    $("#notification-link").on('click', function () {
        $("#notification-modal").modal("openModal");
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#notification-link").trigger("click");
    });
```

But the above popup triggers on every refresh.
I want the popup to load once **once** the site is called or closing and opening the browser again to the page (based on ***session*** expire).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code make changes as per below and check

```
 var popupCookie = $.cookie('popupNewsletterOff');
 if(!popupCookie || popupCookie == 'undefined'){
    var popup = modal(options, $('#notification-modal'));
    $("#notification-link").on('click', function () {
        $("#notification-modal").modal("openModal");
        $.cookie('popupNewsletterOff', true);
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#notification-link").trigger("click");           
    });
 }
```

Comment: the above code is not working and popup has to work based upon session storage. The popup has to open if the user has closed the browser and opened again. In cookies we couldn't achieve it.

Comment: if we don't pass expiry parameter then it works as a session